# How to select the positions of same nodes only in XPATH?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML from which i want to match both star & planet:

```
<stars>
 <star>sss1</star>
 <star>sss2</star>
 <planet>ppp1</planet>
 <star>sss3</star>
 <planet>ppp2</planet>
 <star>sss4</star>
</stars>
```

I want to select the position of the star nodes without considering the planet nodes. E.g. If I use position() on the star I will get the following:

1: sss1

2: sss2

4: sss3

6: sss4

I want to be able to select the position() of star only so I get:

1: sss1

2: sss2

3: sss3

4: sss4

Is there a way to discard other nodes when using the position() function?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="stars">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="star">
    <xsl:element name="h2">
       <xsl:attribute name="class">
           <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
       <xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="planet">
<!-- do something else -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the context of the code, I have to match both star & planet as they appear. I can't do e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="star"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="planet"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: So which nodes do you process/select? Surely if you process e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="/stars/star"/>` then in the template processing those elements the `position()` call will get you the values you have described as the wanted result. And as you use XSLT you also have `<xsl:number/>` which by default will only count the same type of node as the context node or can be configured with its various attributes to count any nodes you are interested in, independently of any currently processed nodes.

Comment: Yes! Number is what i've been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to discard other nodes when using the position() function?

No, but there is a way to discard other nodes when selecting. For example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/stars">
    <xsl:for-each select="star">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
1: sss1
2: sss2
3: sss3
4: sss4
```

---

Alternatively, if it is important to process **all** elements **in their original order**, you could use `xsl:number` instead of `position()` - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/stars">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:number/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
1: sss1
2: sss2
1: ppp1
3: sss3
2: ppp2
4: sss4
```

Comment: @StarniMough Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead, and explain **in detail** what the problem is.

Comment: I've tried the number instead of position() and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot.